# MSBuild: convert relative path in imported project to absolute path

Tags: c#, msbuild

### Short version:

I have an MSBuild project that imports another project. There is a property holding a relative path in the imported project that is relative to the location of the imported project. How do I convert this relative path to be absolute? I've tried the ConvertToAbsolutePath task, but this makes it relative to the importing project's location).

### Long version:

I'm trying out Robert Koritnik's MSBuild task for integrating nunit output into Visual Studio (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850563/visual-studio-integrated-custom-msbuild-task-behaviour) other SO question for a link). Since I like to have all my tools under version control, I want the target file with the custom task in it to point to the nunit console application using a relative path.

My problem is that this relative path ends up being made relative to the importing project.

E.g. (in ... MyRepository\Third Party\NUnit\MSBuild.NUnit.Task.Source\bin\Release\MSBuild.NUnit.Task.Targets):

```
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(NUnitConsoleToolPath)' == ''">
    <NUnitConsoleToolPath>..\..\..\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0</>
  </PropertyGroup>  
...
  <Target Name="IntegratedTest">
    <NUnitIntegrated
      TreatFailedTestsAsErrors="$(NUnitTreatFailedTestsAsErrors)"
      AssemblyName="$(AssemblyName)"
      OutputPath="$(OutputPath)"
      ConsoleToolPath="$(NUnitConsoleToolPath)"
      ConsoleTool="$(NUnitConsoleTool)"
    />
  </Target>
...
```

The above target fails with the error that the file cannot be found (that is the nunit-console.exe file). Inside the NUnitIntegrated MSBuild task, when the the execute() method is called, the current directory is the directory of the **importing** project, so relative paths will point to the wrong location.

I tried to convert the relative path to absolute by adding these tasks to the IntegratedTest target:

```
<ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="$(NUnitConsoleToolPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="AbsoluteNUnitConsoleToolPath"/>
</ConvertToAbsolutePath>
```

but this just converted it to be relative to the directory of the project file that imports this target file.

I know I can use the property `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` to get the directory of the **importing** project, but can't find any equivalent for directory of the **imported** target file.

Can anyone tell me how a path in an imported file that is supposed to be relative to the directory that the imported file is in can be made absolute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to define your relative path with `MSBuildProjectDirectory`

**Importing project :**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RelativePathToProject>subdir\</RelativePathToProject>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(RelativePathToProject)SubSample.proj"/>

<Target Name="GetNUnitConsolePath">
  <Message Text="NUnitConsoleToolPath : %(NUnitConsoleToolPath.FullPath)"/>
</Target>
```

**Imported project file :**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <NUnitConsoleToolPath 
     Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(RelativePathToProject)..\..\..\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('RelativePath'))` to convert your relative path to an absolute path. Note, however, that this will not work on all types of project files. So, for example:

```
$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('..\..\..\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0'))
```