# [MSBUILD]-[Target]-[Import]-relative project path not working on build server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am trying to use a target at a relative location from the project in the source control using the following entry in the .csproj

```
<Import Project="..\..\Shared\Build\Tools\Targets\config.transform.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\Shared\Build\Tools\Targets\config.transform.targets')" />
```

the Shared folder mentioned in the below path is two levels above the .csproj file location as in 
Dashboard\Shared\Build\Tools\Targets
Dashboard\Admin\ConfigurationConsole\ConfigurationConsole.csproj

Locally the project & the solution build fine, but when queued on the build server it fails with the following error.

TransformWebConfig does not exist in the project.

So after trying many things when i finally changed the relative path to the below it worked.

```
<Import Project="..\Shared\Build\Tools\Targets\config.transform.targets" Condition="Exists('..\Shared\Build\Tools\Targets\config.transform.targets')" />
```

Would like to know whats happening here and what could be an apt solution that runs everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

actually the better way to point to a relative path was to force the current path to be current project directory using the $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) environment variable

[Relative paths with MSBuild project vs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775587/relative-paths-with-msbuild-project-vs-solution)

[MSBuild: convert relative path in imported project to absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021177/msbuild-convert-relative-path-in-imported-project-to-absolute-path)